# Leverage Statistic - equation explanation

Tags: notation, leverage

I came across this equation for the leverage statistic in ISL. Does the denominator translate to the summation of all the squares of $(x_i - mean(x))^2$ *excluding the current observation of x*? In other words, does the $x_i'$ stand for *not* $x_i$?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all - the i' is an unfortunate (bad) notation for a generic index, to differentiate it from i which is a specific index used on the left-hand side. A better notation for i' would be j, as this is a common notation for a generic index if i is already used.

Comment: Would you be able to translate the second term in the right side of the equation for me? Something along the lines of, "...the square of the difference between observation i and the sample mean, divided by the summation of ...what...?

Comment: Divided by the sum of the squares of the differences of all observations and the sample mean (including the i-th observation)

Comment: I came across this again later in the book and would like some more clarification if you could. What did you mean when you said "generic index" in your answer? Can I interpret xi' to be the same as xi?