# ISLR - Simplify Equation

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, notation

**The Problem:** I'm working on a problem from the Conceptual exercises from chapter three of "[An Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/index.html)". The problem is asking to show how the top equation below can be rewritten as the bottom equation.

**Self-Study Notes:** This is not for a class, purely for my curiosity. The simplification below is my attempt at the  problem, written using LaTex, not copied from another source.

$$\hat{y_i}~=~x_i\hat{\beta}~~~~~and~~~~~\hat{\beta}~=~\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$$$\hat{y_i}~=~x_i\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$$$\hat{y_i}~=~\left( \frac{x_i}{1} \right)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i'}x_i}{\sum_{i''=1}^n x^2_{i''}} \right)y_{i'}$$$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i'}y_{i'}~~~where~~~ a_{i'}~=~\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i'}x_i}{\sum_{i''=1}^n x^2_{i''}} \right)$$

**Question #1:** I understand everything up until how the third equation becomes the fourth. Why was the additional $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$ added and why was the $y_i$ changed to $y_{i'}$ and moved outside of the summation in the fraction? Why was the $x_i$ able to "move inside" (for lack of a better phrase) of the numerator $\sum_{i=1}^{n}$

$$\hat{y_i}~=~\left( \frac{x_i}{1} \right)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i'}x_i}{\sum_{i''=1}^n x^2_{i''}} \right)y_{i'}$$

**Question #2:** (This could be part of my lack of understanding of the problem) What is the distinction between $x_{i'}$ (with the apostrophe) stand for as opposed to $x_i$ (no apostrophe)? I understand that $x_i$ stands for the *ith* observation, but I don't know what the apostrophe adds to the meaning. I asked a specific question regarding this [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/318854/leverage-statistic-equation-explanation) but would like a more general answer as well

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated. Please type your question as text, do not just post a photograph (see  [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). When you retype the question, please also add the `[self-study]` tag & read  [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The summation identity I needed to solve the equation was $C \cdot \sum_{i=1}^{n}f(x)~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n}C \cdot f(x)$. I believe I've solved it as:
$$\hat{y_i}~=~x_i\hat{\beta}~~~~~and~~~~~\hat{\beta}~=~\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$
$$\hat{y_i}~=~x_i\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$
$$\hat{y_i}~=~\left( \frac{x_i}{1} \right)\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_iy_i}{\sum_{i'=1}^n x^2_{i'}}$$

$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{x_i}{1} \right)\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i'}y_{i'} }{\sum_{k=1}^n x^2_{k}} \right)$$
$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{x_i}{1} \right) \left( \frac{y_i}{1} \right)\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i'} }{\sum_{k=1}^n x^2_{k}} \right)$$
$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{y_i}{1} \right)\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_ix_{i'}}{\sum_{k=1}^n x^2_{k}} \right)$$

$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_{i}x_{i'} }{\sum_{k=1}^n x^2_{k}} \right)y_{i'}$$
$$\hat{y_i}~=~\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_{i'}y_{i'}~~~where~~~ a_{i'}~=~\left( \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} x_ix_{i'} }{\sum_{k=1}^n x^2_{k}} \right)$$

Answer (score 0):

You can replace i' with j and i'' with k and just look for some vector multiplication and you should come up with the desired result.Here (i) just represents a particular observation and i' is not the transpose or complement in this scenario.

Comment: "... i' is not the transpose or complement in this scenario." So if it isn't the transpose or complement, can they be used interchangeably?